# Error: value of type 'Optional<NSMutableArray>' has no subscripts Array[0] in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, nsmutablearray

I am fetching some data from my Objective C classes. Here is my 'dataArray' data:

```
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x2818cff60>(
{
    date = 1574164423;
    shakeState = 1;
},
{
    date = 1574164431;
    shakeState = 1;
}
)
)
```

I have created a Modal class 'ShakeInfo', that contain date and shakeState value.

I just want to convert this Array into array of 'ShakeInfo' object. My problem is when I am trying to print 'dataArray[0]' then I am getting error :

```
error: <EXPR>:3:1: error: value of type 'Optional<NSMutableArray>' has no subscripts
dataArray[0]
```

How can I read this array value index wise. Please advise me.

Edited:

Here is my code after getting dataArray:

```
do {
     let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataArray!)
     let responseStr = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

     print(responseStr)//[{"date":"1574164424","shakeState":1},{"date":"1574164430","shakeState":1}]

     var shakeInfoDetails = [ShakeInfo]()

     //how to add 'responseStr' value in the shakeInfoDetails Modal Array

     } catch {

      print("JSON serialization failed: ", error)
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let data = #"[{"date":"1574164424","shakeState":1},{"date":"1574164430","shakeState":1}]"#.data(using: .utf8)!

//Model

struct ModelRecord : Codable {

    var date : String
    var shakeState : Int
}

class Model {

    var date : Date
    var shakeState : Int

    init?(record: ModelRecord) {

        guard let secondsFrom1970 = Double(record.date) else {
            return nil
        }

        date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
        shakeState = record.shakeState
    }
}

//Decoding

let decoder = JSONDecoder()

do {
    let records = try decoder.decode([ModelRecord].self, from: data)

    let models = records.compactMap { Model(record: $0) }

}
catch {
    print("Decoding Error: \(error)")
}
```

## Answer to original question:

```
let a1 : NSMutableArray? = NSMutableArray(array: ["A", "B", "C"])

a1?.object(at: 2)
```

## Please read about the following:

- Optionals in Swift
- Codable - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types
- Arrays in Swift Standard Library
- NSMutableArray defined in Foundation

Comment: I can get the value of my first index, How can I get both key values for first index?

Comment: A dictionary has key and value but an array only has values ordered. Not sure I understand your question. Are you looking for a dictionary or an array ?

Comment: Yes, I need my data as Modal array or dictionary.

Comment: The object shown in the original question is a mutable array and not a dictionary. If you want it as a dictionary convert it into a dictionary using your business logic. Edit the question appropriately to reflect what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have an another doubt here. Please see my edited question. My question is how to add 'responseStr' value in the shakeInfoDetails Modal Array?

Comment: Yes.. Thank you so much.

Comment: Codable refer to: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types